# Does this blur background effect have a specific name

Tags: terminology

https://youtu.be/f-qTGM5wsnM?t=114

The entire video is a tutorial on how to achieve the desired effect, the snippet [linked](https://youtu.be/f-qTGM5wsnM?t=114) is a demo of it.

In words the image/video is taken, expanded to fill and blurred. Does it have a specific name I can google and read more about ?

Comment: Looks like Gaussian blur

Comment: @PaulHK I think the question is about the way it's used, to pad out the image, rather than about the type of blur itself.